# How to check if the process was executed successfully in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing, command-prompt

I try to create a windows batch script that install nodeJs, express and bower, but for now doesn't work and I cant know what is the problem because the terminal closed after some seconds. 
If I run all the instructions of the batch script one by one into a CMD all work OK.
How can I validate that every process was executed successfully? I mean if the install of express fail, get a message like `"fail express framework install"`
I think that the problem is the script **doesn't wait finished install the fisrt block of code when try to install the next block**.
Any idea for resolve?

**This is my script:**

---

```
::Windows Batch Script for Install nodeJs, express framework for nodeJs, bower and Ionic

@setlocal
@echo off
:: Install nodeJs & NPM
echo Instalando NodeJs ^& NPM (Node Package Manager)...
echo.
start /wait msiexec /i C:\EMWA\installers\node.msi /passive /norestart

::Install express framework
echo Instalando express framework nodejs
echo.
npm install express-generator -g

:: Install bower
echo Install bower
echo.
npm install -g bower

:: create a test project
IF NOT EXIST C:\EMWA\projects 
    mkdir C:\EMWA\projects
IF NOT EXIST C:\EMWA\projects\emwa_test
    mkdir C:\EMWA\projects\emwa_test

pause > null
```

Comment: run the program and check `errorlevel` variavle, if it's ` = 0` run sucessfully otherwise error

Answer (score 0):

This is the purpose of the `ERRORLEVEL` keyword in the `IF` statement. See `IF /?` for details:

```
C:\...>if /?
Performs conditional processing in batch programs.

IF [NOT] ERRORLEVEL number command
....

  NOT               Specifies that Windows should carry out
                    the command only if the condition is false.

  ERRORLEVEL number Specifies a true condition if the last program run
                    returned an exit code equal to or greater than the number
                    specified.
....
%ERRORLEVEL% will expand into a string representation of
the current value of ERRORLEVEL, provided that there is not already
an environment variable with the name ERRORLEVEL, in which case you
will get its value instead.  After running a program, the following
illustrates ERRORLEVEL use:

    goto answer%ERRORLEVEL%
    :answer0
    echo Program had return code 0
    :answer1
    echo Program had return code 1

You can also use numerical comparisons above:

    IF %ERRORLEVEL% LEQ 1 goto okay
....
C:\...>
```

This works as long as the commands set an exit status, which many do.